# Extra [ ] in layer QGIS Python Console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-python-console

I'm trying to write a "simple" plugin as training and to automate a task repetitive task as well.  I would like to have the map layer hardcoded instead of make sure you select the correct one but if I use mapLayersByName it adds [ and ] to start and end of layer which makes it think its a list. I can fix this by using Layer[0].getFeatures() instead of normally using Layer.getFeatures()

What causes this?

```
Layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Parry Sound FDSA Boundaries')
layer = iface.activeLayer()

print(Layer)
[<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x000001D610F0AD38>]

print(layer)
<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x000001D610F0AD38>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is by [design](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a935efacacb942a15afe19728233e35c3)

> Retrieve a **list** of matching registered layers by layer name.

You could have several layers having the same name